# Error Code: 1052. Column 'id' in IN/ALL/ANY subquery is ambiguous

Tags: mysql, sql

```
    Left join ( select * from crif_stage2 where id in 
    ( select id from  ( select user_id, max(id) as id from
    crif_stage2 group by 1)a)) cf2 on l.user_id = cf2.user_id
```

Edit : exactly where should I add table name (a) in this query ?

Comment: Write it down, remember, learn: If the query source contains more than one table (different tables or copies of the same table) then **each column name must be specified with definite table name/alias**. And the same if local variables are visible/used. Also each table copy in the query must be assigned with an alias which is **unique over the whole query**.

Comment: `select id from` should be `select a.id from` I guess. It would have been better if you formatted the query a bit and added some of the additional joins before and after it.

Answer (score 0):

Left join
( select * from crif_stage2
where id in
( select a.id from
( select user_id, max(id) as id from
crif_stage2 group by 1) a
)
) cf2 on l.user_id = cf2.user_id

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: don't suppose there is any need to explain anything @NicoHaase . OP asked about where to put the alias and I posted corrected query in response, what's there to explain? it's just a small query